# Why my send and receive Object sometime is different?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, network-programming

I trying to send an object by server to receiver or reverse.However, most of time it is true and done completely but sometimes when I send an object, the receiver get the object that I sent before it and object are sent by sender lost.I have used Socket in my project and read and write by ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Looks like a straightforward question to me.

Comment: I agree. It is certainly a duplicate but @ColinMorelli and friends there is nothing unclear about it, and it has a simple well-documented solution. Please don't vote to close just because you don't know anything about the topic yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the same object with different values you need to call ObjectOutputStream.reset() before the second send if you want the receiver to get the changed object. Or call writeUnshared() instead of writeObject().